# PDO uso de LIKE en la consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql, pdo

Tengo el siguiente código

```
$damn = '%'.$busqueda.'%';
            $q_i = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM registro_viaje WHERE (id_pas_reg LIKE ? OR nomc_pas_reg LIKE ? OR tel_pas_reg LIKE ?) AND matricula_veh_reg=?');
            $q_i->bindParam(1,$damn);
            $q_i->bindParam(2,$damn);
            $q_i->bindParam(3,$damn);
            $q_i->bindParam(4,$matricula);
            $q_i->execute();
            $q_r = $q_i->fetchAll();
            if (count($q_r)>0) {
                print_r($q_r);
            }else{
                echo "Nada, papú :(";
            }
```

En la base de datos, hay información acerca de **Felipe Solano**, entonces **$busqueda** es igual a "Felipe", al arrancar el código resulta que no hay resultados... 
**NOTESE** el uso del **LIKE**, en qué estoy fallando aquí?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba el siguiente codigo:

```
$damn = "Tu busqueda";
$q_i = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM registro_viaje WHERE id_pas_reg LIKE ? OR nomc_pas_reg LIKE ? OR tel_pas_reg LIKE ? AND matricula_veh_reg=?');
$q_i->bindValue(1,"%{$damn}%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q_i->bindValue(2,"%{$damn}%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q_i->bindValue(3,"%{$damn}%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q_i->bindValue(4,$matricula);
$q_i->execute();
$q_r = $q_i->fetchAll();
if (count($q_r)>0) {
    print_r($q_r);
}else{
    echo "Nada, papú :(";
}
```

Ten en cuenta que si la clausula AND no se cumple no te traera nada de la DB. 
Saludos.